# EKS container cannot reach DynamoDb or other AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

We have deployed alpine images on EKS Fargate nodes, and have also associated a service account to an IAM role which has access to DynamoDb and some other services.
When deploying the containers, we can see that AWS has automatically set these env vars on all containers

```
AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::1111111:role/my-role
AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token
```

But if we execute this command with the cli

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

or

```
aws dynamodb list-tables
```

the command simply hangs and does not return any results.

We have followed the docs on setting up the iam roles for the EKS (k8s) service accounts - is there anything more we need to do to check the connectivity from the containers to the DynamoDb for example? (please note, from Lambda or so we can access DynamoDb - an endpoint exists for the necessary services)

When I execute this on the pod:

````
aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity \ --role-arn $AWS_ROLE_ARN \ --role-session-name mh9test \ --web-identity-token ```
file://$AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE \ --duration-seconds 1000
````

I get this error: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "sts.amazonaws.com" which is strange because the vpc endpoint is sts.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
I can also not ping endpoint address such as ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Is the cluster security group allowed outbound traffic?

Comment: yes, outbound all traffic is allowed. When I execute this on the pod: aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity \
--role-arn $AWS_ROLE_ARN \
--role-session-name mh9test \
--web-identity-token file://$AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE \
--duration-seconds 1000 I get this error: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://sts.amazonaws.com/" which is strange because the vpc endpoint is sts.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: so my next guess is going to be, check all popssible network security rules that you might have configured. At the same time though, I'd try spiceworks or serverfault rather than stackoverflow.